# Is artificial intelligence really possible?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I always wonder if artificial intelligence is really possible?

What I mean is, if there is someone who codes all these possibilities and the actions need to be taken, isn't it impossible? The number of possibilities are infinity in real world. If so, all the fancy "Artificial Intelligence" is a big lie?

Or is this really possible to have an algorithm which will recursively creates more possibilities and its actions need to be taken in  an infinite loop?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Worldbuilding question.  CS maybe?  Not sure of their rules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about whether something is possible in the real world, not about any aspect of building a fictional one. It sounds like philosophy might be the place to go.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

I recommend you to read [The Second Machine Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Second_Machine_Age:_Work,_Progress,_and_Prosperity_in_a_Time_of_Brilliant_Technologies) book for better understanding of what is now going on:

[Moore's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) still holds on, and the above mentioned book assumes, that it will still be valid for next 20 years.

Today, in 2015 we are in situation which was "unthinkable" in 2000:

- Self driving cars
- Speech recognition, including understanding questions asked in natural language
- Internet in every pocket

We already are in times, where AI exists. What we still miss is general purpose AI. But we will get there dangerously soon

Comment: Thx for the reply but those "unthinkable" things are valid because they have been coded by someone! 20 years later, maybe another million of possibilities will be considered in algorithms but million, billion or trillion is nothing if you compare with infinity! Thanks for the book suggestion, I will definitely look in to it!

Comment: The thing is: In given day you have infinite possibilities in what to do. If you are given "just" 5 billion possibilities what to do, it would be enough to get you through the day. And, we also have self learning machines ;)\

Comment: @PavelJanicek - I disagree that we are anywhere near creating a true AI. We have created some pretty clever algorithms, but they are still severely limited. I don't think we're going to see a true AI spring up anytime soon.